# How to make Trino(prev. presto) to log in JSON format

Tags: log4j2, presto, trino

Looking for solution to make Trino logs(worker and coordinator) in JSON format, tried to replace log4j jars with log4j2 or logback with appropriate configuration, but neither worked, from DOCKER file:

```
RUN tar  --exclude="*log4j*.jar"  --directory /opt/ -xzf /opt/presto-server-${PRESTO_VERSION}.tar.gz
COPY log4j/*.jar /opt/presto/lib/
```

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `log.format=json` to the server configuration file.

Comment: Appreciate that you've checked this @Martin, suggestion is to change log.properties ? Tried and server failed to start, what I missing ?    

 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.airlift.log.Level.JSON  at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)  at io.airlift.log.Level.valueOf(Level.java:3)  at io.airlift.log.Logging.lambda$setLevels$0(Logging.java:152)  at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.forEach(RegularImmutableMap.java:292) at io.airlift.log.Logging.setLevels(Logging.java:151)  at io.airlift.log.Logging.configure(Logging.java:235)`

Comment: What version of Trino are you running?

Comment: The option goes in the config.properties file, not in the log.properties file. The latter is only for configuring log levels.

Comment: We're using v374, also tried v386, meanwhile without success, this should work on coordinator, right ? May be need to add appender or logback.xml ?

Comment: It should work on those versions. Make sure to add the option to the `config.properties` file, not the `log.properties` file (see above comment)

Comment: After code checking and debugging understood that JSON support is only supported in files by using an option above, hoped to setup trino to log JSON to stdout. Anyway accepting @MartinTraverso answer and will try to add support for that in airlift code.